# zip extraction on zip files in different languages

Tags: java

I have a simple extraction method in java using the java.util.zip package.

Edit: as a note, I am required to run the code in java 1.5 because it has to be run as a java stored procedure within an oracle database.

It has been working perfectly for quite some time but recently I ran into a bug when I tried to extract a zip file that contained spanish special characters in the name and a file within it that had spanish special characters.

The code fails on

```
 ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
```

Is this due to the special characters? I have verified that the zip is not corrupt and have tested on other zips with special characters in the name and have verified that it causes the same error.

Lastly, if this is the case, is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that org.apache.commons has a compression class and that has a bunch of different options. It allows you to specify an encoding parameter so it will accept characters from different languages now.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7 you can use a [ZipFile(File, Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) indicating the character encoding.

Comment: About which Charset Cp1252 (Windows), Cp850 (DOS) might be tried first.

Comment: I am required to use java 1.5 because it is running as a java stored procedure within an oracle database

Comment: Maybe - if you are very lucky - you can try-catch the getNextEntry, invent a file name, and continue. Or terribly hack by setting the global file encoding. Better report a failure, and do it then in a web app.